# Android - Different ActionBar depending on the Fragment in a tabbed Activity

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, fragment

The title says it all. I was wondering if I could modify the action bar items depending on the fragment displayed on a tabbed Activity. If it is possible how should I do this stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Toolbar` instead of an `ActionBar`.
http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example 
You can make as many Toolbars as you need, and show and hide them on  `tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(...)` the way  Сергей Боиштян described.
I find Toolbars easier to customize and less messy than Actionbars

Comment: If you find the way to tab a toolbar the correct answer is yours. Challenge accepted?

Comment: Haha, I'll take the bait. It's actually fairly simple:
You could use a SlidingTabLayout
https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java 
which works with a ViewPager.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm mentioning that SlidingTabLayout simply because I like that effect, but really you could use the default Android tabs.

Comment: Great ! You are convincing me. And aesthetically how is it?

Comment: Look at that example on the link I sent. It looks like an ActionBar except you can treat it as a normal layout which is great for customization. You can even feed it a menu.xml  for normal menu icons and the three dot hidden menu type. You can do everything :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this.

```
public class UserTabsActivity extends BaseActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {

private MenuItem                       settingsItem;
private MenuItem                       actionSearch;
private SearchView                     searchView;
private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener onQueryTextListener;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.user_tabs_menu, menu);
    settingsItem = menu.findItem(R.id.settings_item);
    settingsItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

    actionSearch = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) actionSearch.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint(Constants.USER_HINT);
    searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(onQueryTextListener);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    customize(tabId)
}
public void customize(String currentTab) {
    switch (currentTab) {
        case "sometag":
            settingsItem.setVisible(false);
            actionSearch.setVisible(true);
            break;
        default:
            settingsItem.setVisible(true);
            actionSearch.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

And in you fragment yo can write some logic

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    FragmentTabHost tabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
    tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), android.R.id.content);

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("users").setIndicator("ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛИ"), SomeFragment.class, null);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("posts").setIndicator("ПОСТЫ"), SomeFragment.class, null);

    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener((TabHost.OnTabChangeListener) getActivity());

    return tabHost;
}
```

In that code is the most important tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(..) and
UserTabsActivity extends BaseActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener
This is one of the possibilities. I hoped, this is helpfull